# How to dynamically handle a file with missing column names in ADF pipeline?

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-data-factory

I am copying data from ADLS csv file to Azure SQL DB.
File contains 9 columns and mapping is done according to that, but sometimes the source file is only having 6 or 7 columns. In that case the pipeline is failing with error

> The name of column index 'x' is empty. Make sure column name is properly specified in the header row

Even some columns are missing I want to copy other columns data which is available and ignore the missing columns.
How can I dynamically handle this case and do mapping in case some columns are missing? As the files from source will have different set of columns each time.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the mapping from the copy activity so it will try to map automatically.

**Note:** the column order in csv file should match the column order in table

Comment: I have 9 files and i am trying to copy those to 9 different tables, for that I only need one pipeline. I have stored the mapping in a table and i am fetching that mapping in json format. and according to that copying the data.

Comment: For copying 9 files you can using For Each activity and if you hardcode the mapping and use that in copy activity if the columns are not there in the file it will fail.

Comment: better to keep automapping and try to match the column headers of the CSV file with Table column names

Answer (score 0):

I created pipeline and performed get metadata activity with  `Column count` field to get the number of columns of my csv file which is in ADLS account by selecting the ADLS dataset. After successful execution of metadata activity connected with lookup activity. selected sql database dataset for lookup and executed below code to find the number of columns of my sql table.

```
SELECT  COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) as c
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_CATALOG =  '<database>'  AND TABLE_SCHEMA =  '<schema>'
AND TABLE_NAME =  '<table>'
```

After successful execution of look up connected to if condition and given below expression to compare the columns of meta data activity and lookup activity

```
@equals(activity('Get Metadata1').output.columnCount,activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.c)
```

If it is true I implemented copy activity to copy data from adls to sql by following below procedure

Selected delimited text dataset by selecting csv file from adls linked service as source enable first row as header in dataset

[image]

and select sql database dataset as sink and imported the schema in mapping of copy activity.
If it is false I implemented dynamic mapping following below procedure:
I created table in sql database with below columns

```
create  table table_mappings(

    sourceFile nvarchar(30),
    sinkTableSchema nvarchar(30),
    sinkTableName nvarchar(30),
    jsonMapping nvarchar(max)
)
```

Inserted below values

```
insert  into table_mappings values('<sourcefilename>','<schema>','<tablename>','{"type": "TabularTranslator",

"mappings": [
             {
                "source": {
                    "name": "EMPLOYEE_ID",
                    "type": "String",
                    "physicalType": "String"
                 },
                "sink": {
                    "name": "EMPLOYEE_ID",
                    "type": "String",
                    "physicalType": "String"
                }
            },
            {
                "source": {
                    "name": "FIRST_NAME",
                    "type": "String",
                    "physicalType": "String"
                 },
                 "sink": {
                    "name": "FIRST_NAME",
                    "type": "String",
                    "physicalType": "String"
                }
           }
       ]}')
```

In jsonMapping column inserted columns of source and columns of table where the values need to store with above format.

[image]

I implemented lookup activity to by selecting sql database dataset and entered below query

```
select * from table_mappings where sourceFile = '<filename>'
```

[image]

After successful execution of lookup created connected to copy activity. selected adls delimited text as source and sql database dataset as sink and created two parameters in sink named schema with `@activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.sinkTableSchema`  value and table with `@activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.sinkTableName`
and used those parameters for selecting the table in dataset as `@dataset().schema`.`@dataset().table` I added mapping dynamically using `@json(activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.jsonMapping)`
executed the pipeline, it executed successfully.

[image]

Here is my Json of pipeline:

```
{
    "name": "pipeline3",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Lookup1",
                "type": "Lookup",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Get Metadata1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "AzureSqlSource",
                        "sqlReaderQuery": "SELECT COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) as c\nFROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS \nWHERE TABLE_CATALOG = 'db' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'\nAND TABLE_NAME = 'employees'  ",
                        "queryTimeout": "02:00:00",
                        "partitionOption": "None"
                    },
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "AzureSqlTable1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Get Metadata1",
                "type": "GetMetadata",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "DelimitedText2",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "fieldList": [
                        "columnCount"
                    ],
                    "storeSettings": {
                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                    },
                    "formatSettings": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "If Condition1",
                "type": "IfCondition",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Lookup1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "expression": {
                        "value": "@equals(activity('Get Metadata1').output.columnCount,activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.c)",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "ifFalseActivities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Copy data1_copy1",
                            "type": "Copy",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Lookup1_copy1",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "source": {
                                    "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                                        "recursive": true,
                                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                    },
                                    "formatSettings": {
                                        "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                                    }
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "type": "AzureSqlSink",
                                    "writeBehavior": "insert",
                                    "sqlWriterUseTableLock": false
                                },
                                "enableStaging": false,
                                "translator": {
                                    "value": "@json(activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.jsonMapping)",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            },
                            "inputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "DelimitedText2",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                                }
                            ],
                            "outputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "AzureSqlTable2",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "schema": {
                                            "value": "@activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.sinkTableSchema",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        },
                                        "table": {
                                            "value": "@activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.sinkTableName",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Lookup1_copy1",
                            "type": "Lookup",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "source": {
                                    "type": "AzureSqlSource",
                                    "sqlReaderQuery": "select * from table_mappings where sourceFile = 'employees.csv'",
                                    "queryTimeout": "02:00:00",
                                    "partitionOption": "None"
                                },
                                "dataset": {
                                    "referenceName": "AzureSqlTable1",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "ifTrueActivities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Copy data1",
                            "type": "Copy",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "source": {
                                    "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                                        "recursive": true,
                                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                    },
                                    "formatSettings": {
                                        "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                                    }
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "type": "AzureSqlSink",
                                    "writeBehavior": "insert",
                                    "sqlWriterUseTableLock": false,
                                    "disableMetricsCollection": false
                                },
                                "enableStaging": false,
                                "translator": {
                                    "type": "TabularTranslator",
                                    "mappings": [
                                        {
                                            "source": {
                                                "name": "EMPLOYEE_ID",
                                                "type": "String",
                                                "physicalType": "String"
                                            },
                                            "sink": {
                                                "name": "EMPLOYEE_ID",
                                                "type": "String",
                                                "physicalType": "String"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "source": {
                                                "name": "FIRST_NAME",
                                                "type": "String",
                                                "physicalType": "String"
                                            },
                                            "sink": {
                                                "name": "FIRST_NAME",
                                                "type": "String",
                                                "physicalType": "String"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "source": {
                                                "name": "LAST_NAME",
                                                "type": "String",
                                                "physicalType": "String"
                                            },
                                            "sink": {
                                                "name": "LAST_NAME",
                                                "type": "String",
                                                "physicalType": "String"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "source": {
                                                "name": "EMAIL",
                                                "type": "String",
                                                "physicalType": "String"
                                            },
                                            "sink": {
                                                "name": "EMAIL",
                                                "type": "String",
                                                "physicalType": "String"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "source": {
                                                "name": "PHONE_NUMBER",
                                                "type": "String",
                                                "physicalType": "String"
                                            },
                                            "sink": {
                                                "name": "PHONE_NUMBER",
                                                "type": "String",
                                                "physicalType": "String"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "source": {
                                                "name": "HIRE_DATE",
                                                "type": "String",
                                                "physicalType": "String"
                                            },
                                            "sink": {
                                                "name": "HIRE_DATE",
                                                "type": "String",
                                                "physicalType": "String"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "source": {
                                                "name": "JOB_ID",
                                                "type": "String",
                                                "physicalType": "String"
                                            },
                                            "sink": {
                                                "name": "JOB_ID",
                                                "type": "String",
                                                "physicalType": "String"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "source": {
                                                "name": "SALARY",
                                                "type": "String",
                                                "physicalType": "String"
                                            },
                                            "sink": {
                                                "name": "SALARY",
                                                "type": "String",
                                                "physicalType": "String"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "source": {
                                                "name": "COMMISSION_PCT",
                                                "type": "String",
                                                "physicalType": "String"
                                            },
                                            "sink": {
                                                "name": "COMMISSION_PCT",
                                                "type": "String",
                                                "physicalType": "String"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "source": {
                                                "name": "MANAGER_ID",
                                                "type": "String",
                                                "physicalType": "String"
                                            },
                                            "sink": {
                                                "name": "MANAGER_ID",
                                                "type": "String",
                                                "physicalType": "String"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "source": {
                                                "name": "DEPARTMENT_ID",
                                                "type": "String",
                                                "physicalType": "String"
                                            },
                                            "sink": {
                                                "name": "DEPARTMENT_ID",
                                                "type": "String",
                                                "physicalType": "String"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "typeConversion": true,
                                    "typeConversionSettings": {
                                        "allowDataTruncation": true,
                                        "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "inputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "DelimitedText1",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                                }
                            ],
                            "outputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "AzureSqlTable1",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "hello": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

If there are multiple files then perform above activities in foreach loop.